# Minimalist accordion implementation using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

The following example is an accordion script in JavaScript that does not use jQuery. When I started looking for a simple solution to this requirement I did not accept the idea of having to use a powerful and robust library for a simple implementation. I didn't like the idea of use a machine gun when what I really need is a slingshot. So as a jQuery detox process I decide create my own solution. So far the code is simple enough and I’m planning using it in production as a custom widget in my blog running Wordpress. I’m very enthusiast of minimalist development and I have some concerns with this code.

Any suggestions about how I can achieve a simpler and elegant solution? I was thinking in implementing the [`element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) properties.

[Here](http://codepen.io/jamespr/pen/yyxXNP) is a live demo of the accordion script.

**HTML**

```html
<aside id="archives" class="widget widget_archive"><h3 class="widget-title">Archivos</h3>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">2015</a>
      <a href="#"<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">febrero 2015</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">enero 2015</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2014</a>
      <a href="#"<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="hide">
        <li><a href="#">diciembre 2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">noviembre 2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">marzo 2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">febrero 2014</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">enero 2014</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">2013</a>
      <a href="#"<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="hide">
        <li><a href="#">diciembre 2013</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">septiembre 2013</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```html
.widget 
{
  width:60%;
  margin:50px auto 0 auto;
  border:4px solid rgba(10,10,10,0.05);
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 45px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 45px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 45px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.widget-title
{
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color:#636363;
  padding-bottom:10px
}

.widget a
{
  color:#9b9b9b;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px 0 10px 10px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.widget a + a
{
  padding:10px 16px;
  float:right;
  line-height:1.5;
}

.widget a + a:hover
{
  background-color:#ddd;
  color:#fff;
}

.widget a:hover
{
  color:#444
}

.widget ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background-color:#eee;
}

.widget ul 
{
  line-height:1.5;
}

.widget li
{
  border-top:1px solid #ccc;
}

.widget li li 
{
  line-height:1.5;
  border-top:1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color:#fff;
}

.widget > ul li:first-child 
li a:first-child {
  display:inline-block;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}
```

**JS**

```html
"use strict";

var elementum = document.querySelector(".widget_archive");
var gestus = elementum.getElementsByClassName("fa");

for (var i = 0; i < gestus.length; i++) {
  gestus[i].addEventListener("click", toogle);
}

function toogle()
{
  if (this.nextElementSibling.className === "")
  {
    this.nextElementSibling.className = "hide";
  }
  else
  {
    this.nextElementSibling.className = ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Big fan of minimalist code.  I once upon a time used jQuery also.  Life is much better without it.  I applaud your efforts.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and support @Misunderstood. I firmly believe that we must know our tools and know where we can use them. I believe in jQuery and in other frameworks like Velocity.js and Underscore.js to name a few. But there is no greater satisfaction than knowing what problems frameworks solve and when to use them in our projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should use `classList`. Right now you overwrite the entire `className` attribute of the elements. It works, but it also means that you can never use any other class name on the elements. So it's just not a very precise or robust way of doing things; it only works as long as you don't add other classes. And if you *do* need to add another class to the elements at some point, your script will mess up because the comparison with `""` will always fail, and then any and all class names will get summarily removed by your script.

Of course, [`classList` isn't supported everywhere](http://caniuse.com/#search=classlist), so you may have to use a shim/polyfill. The `nextElementSibling` property isn't supported everywhere either, by the way (which, incidentally is why jQuery exists; because browser compatibility is not simple).

I also wonder why you use `querySelector` in one line, but `elementsByClassName` in the next line. In both cases you want to find element(s) with a given class name. Of course, in the first case, you want exactly 1 element, and in the other you want a collection. However, if you want *1 particular element*, you should probably add an `id` attribute to that element - not a class - and then use the good old `document.getElementById`. In other words: Using a class selector and expecting it to only exist on one element is backwards. Classes are *meant* to be used on an arbitrary number of elements. If you want unique identification, use an `id` instead.

Also, please don't mix languages in your code. I know it's only two variable names, but *especially* because it's only two variable names there's no reason to switch language. The DOM API is in English, and even all your CSS classes are in English, so it's simpler and cleaner to just stick to that (by the way, I'm not a native English speaker myself, I just prefer code to be consistent.)

Lastly, I always recommend that you use brace-on-same-line style in JavaScript. There are some assumptions about style in JS interpreters, and brace-on-same-line is one.

Comment: Hey @Flambino a got a few comments about your answer, do you like to discuss it in a chat?

Comment: @James Sorry, been away. But feel free to ask here in the comments. I'll get to it, when I have the chance.

Comment: The action to overwrite the className attribute is to avoid an initialization function in the js script. By this I mean a function that only display the current year panel leaving the others hides. I decided that I can achieve this by attaching the `.hide` class to the elements containing past years (this is donde in the backend side). Since I don't perceive using any class on those elements I decided to overwrite it. Also if I decide to edit the style I can easily target them with some css selectors.

Comment: I don’t clearly understand why comparison with `""` will always fail, I use it for the toggling, but maybe I’m missing something.

Comment: The option to use a shim is basically a fact if I want to increase browser compatibility and for this little script will be the best bet.

Comment: I used `querySelector` and `getElementsByClassName` because I thought is more performant (maybe I’m wrong). Since the Wordpress widget use a specific class for the archive widget but also add others classes I thought `querySelector` will quickly transvers the DOM to select the desire section of the html that will be modified by the script. Then using `getElementsByClassName` on that scope I can attach easily the toggle behavior.

Comment: I totally agree with you in don’t mixing languages in the code. I used the very early prototyping and left it in the example. But is already fixed in the CodePen live [demo](http://codepen.io/jamespr/pen/yyxXNP). Also, I implement the brace-on-same-line style.

Comment: @James Yes, keep adding the initial `hide` class in the HTML - that's the right approach. But completely overwriting `className` afterward is just kinda inelegant. Your JS is acting like a shotgun when it should be a scalpel. If you _do_ need to add another class name one day, your JS suddenly breaks everything. If you add another class, the comparison fails, and the class you added suddenly gets removed. Not ideal - you don't want your JS to break your page.

Comment: @James As for `querySelector`, my point was just that you're looking for a single, unique element. And in that case, the element should have an ID - not a class. A class is intended to be used my _multiple_ elements, so it doesn't make sense to look for a class selector, when you only want one element. So, I'd use an ID. And if you add an ID, you can just as well use `getElementById`. By the way, I'll tweak my answer a little to clarify some things.

Comment: @Flambio Thanks a lot for your feedback. To avoid overwriting the class resulted in an exercise more complex that was I thought. The almost final code is [here](http://codepen.io/jamespr/pen/yyxXNP.js).

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it there are two accordion styles.

1. Expand and Contract (ec) the one Section where multiple Sections can be
   Expanded or Contracted.
2. Only one Section is Expanded at any given time. (ecp ec paired)

### HTML

```
<button class="link" type="button" onclick ="ec('s1')">Button</button>
<div id="s1" class="hide">

</div>

<button class="link" type="button" onclick ="ec('s2')">Button</button>
<div id="s2" class="hide">

</div>
<div id="s999"></div>
```

### JS

I have two functions one for each the two EC methods.
function ec() is for EC method 1
functions ecp() is for EC method 2, pairs the current selected section with the previous.
Normally obe one of these functions is used on a web page.

The div id="s999" is for the initial value for `prev` so there is no null value to prev.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
toggle[''] = 'block';
toggle['none'] = 'block';
toggle['block'] = 'none';
function ec(id){
  div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.style.display=toggle[div.style.display];
  var y=div.offsetTop;window.scrollTo(0, y-64);
}



var prev = document.getElementById('s999');
function ecp(id){ 
  div = document.getElementById(id);
  var disp = div.style.display;
  prev.style.display='none';
  div.style.display=toggle[disp];
  prev=div;
  var y=div.offsetTop;window.scrollTo(0, y-64);
}

//]]>
</script>
```

The reason I have var `disp = div.style.display;` is for when the same section is selected as previously.  I do not care if `prev` is expanded or contracted just contracting it is much quicker than an else if to check its display state.  But I need to remember what I am doing with the passed `id`.  If the same section is clicked and I toggle the display state, if it is being expanded the `prev` toggle would contract it again.

The line of code:

```
var y=div.offsetTop;window.scrollTo(0, y-64);
```

Takes the expanded section and puts it at the top of the Browser window. When all are contracted, it scrolls to the very top or the page.

The reason I use an array for the toggle is to eliminate the else if that would otherwise be required.

I review every line of code as to how it will be compiled to machine code and then executed in the microprocessor execution engine and micro code.  This is a fallback to when I started out in this business designing integrated circuits

I keep myself up to date with each new Intel micro architecture by reading Intel's Intel's 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual

[Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.html)

All programmers should be familiar with this manual.

You don't have to read all 642 pages.  At a minimum read Chapter 3

> Chapter 3 ***General Optimization Guidelines***

and  and read the *User/Source Coding Rules*. 
 Search the document using this search phrase: "User/Source Coding Rule".

### Button vs Anchor

I prefer to use a button rather than an `<a>` anchor.  The button is so much easier to style.    I almost look at button as an enhanced `<div>`.  The button's default display style is `inline-block`.  Not so much  an issue today, but inline-block was problematic with Browser support.

Using `<a>` with an `href` value of "#" is a jQuery thing.  Not a good thing either.  If you need to use an `<a>` as an actual link a a button can still be used. Just wrap a form around it. (Not SEO friendly)

```
<form action="link to where ever"><button type="submit">Link Text</button></form>
```

It also makes it easy to make a link a post and include hidden inputs

A post link can remedy cache no-cache issues.  No cache use post, cached use get.

to make it SEO friendly you would need to add the `<a href>` elsewhere.